# A* algorithm vs uninformed search

Tags: algorithm, search

In which case A* algorithm becomes the same as an uninformed searching algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A* search algorithm decays to [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for the admissible heuristic function `h(v) = 0` for all `v`, since in this case you get `f(v) = g(v) + h(v) = g(v) + 0 = g(v)`, and you chose the best first. This is pretty much equivalent to Dijkstra's Algorithm.

For an unweighted graph, Dijsktra's algorithm is a variant of [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), so you can say it (A*) decays to BFS in unweighted graphs with `h(v) = 0`.

Comment: Dijkstra's Algorithm is a type of A*